# Сумма в зависимости от значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть 2 слайдера(input range) подскажите, как в зависимости от значений month и cash менять значение формулы. Думал функцию создать и передавать параметры, но что-то туплю

```
сумма = cash * (13/100)*month

$( ".cash #slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1000,
        max: 500000,
        value: 1000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".cash #amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $( ".cash .amount" ).html( ui.value +"в‚Ѕ" );
        }
    });
    $( ".cash #amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) +"в‚Ѕ" );
    $( ".cash .amount" ).html( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value") +"в‚Ѕ" );

    $( ".month #range-mounth").slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 12,
        value: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".month #amount" ).val( ui.value );
            $( ".month .amount" ).html( ui.value +" месяцев" );
        }
    });
    $( ".month #amount" ).val( $( "#range-mounth" ).slider( "value" ) +" месяцев" );
    $( ".month .amount" ).html( $( "#range-mounth" ).slider( "value" ) +" месяцев" );
```

Comment: ппц, за что минус? натолкните на мысль хотя  бы, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: у меня да ползунка, это две разных функции .slider есть одна формула, и в зависимости от значений каждого из ползунка, должно подставляться значения их в формулы

Comment: Так их много или одна, ну формул этих?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде такого?

```js
$(function () {

 function calcSumm() {
  var cash = +$("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value");
  var months = +$("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value");
  var summ = cash * (13 / 100) * months;
  $(".summ").html(summ);
 }

 $(".cash #slider-range-max-cash").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1000,
  max: 500000,
  value: 1000,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   $(".cash #amount").val(ui.value);
   calcSumm();
  }
 });
 $(".cash #amount").val($("#slider-range-max-cash").slider("value"));

 $(".month #slider-range-max-month").slider({
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 12,
  value: 1,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   $(".month #month").val(ui.value);
   calcSumm();
  }
 });
 $(".month #month").val($("#slider-range-max-month").slider("value"));
  
 calcSumm();

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.cash,
.month {
  width: 50%;
}

#amount,
#month {
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div class="cash">
  <label for="amount">Price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">в‚Ѕ
  
  <div id="slider-range-max-cash"></div>

</div>

<br>

 <div class="month">
  <label for="month">Month:</label>
  <input type="text" id="month" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">месяцев
  
  <div id="slider-range-max-month"></div>

</div>


<br>

<div>Сумма: <span class="summ"></span></div>
```